# Christoffel symbols and measurements of acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, geodesics

In some coordinates $x^a$, the equation of motion for a particle of unit mass is
\begin{equation}
  \ddot x^i + \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot x^j \dot x^k = F^i
\end{equation}

My questions is simple: Suppose I measure the particle's acceleration. Is the value I obtain the value of $\ddot x^i$ or of $ \ddot x^i + \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot x^j \dot x^k$.

**My thoughts:**

To be more concrete, the situation I have in mind is that of Euclidean space where I am recording all of my values in spherical coordinates.

What I typically think of as the 'acceleration' is 
\begin{equation}
\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = (\ddot r, \ddot \phi, \ddot\theta)
\end{equation}

If the particle is not 'accelerating' (*i.e* if $\ddot{\mathbf r} = 0$) then it is certainly not moving in a straight line (if you assume that $\dot \theta =0$, you get a spiral).  To obtain a straight line the particle needs to follow the above equation with ($F=0$) in which case the particle is in fact 'accelerating':
\begin{equation}
  \ddot x^i = - \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot x^j \dot x^k
\end{equation}
But this of course means that the particle is not accelerating in Cartesian coordinates. Based on this, I am guessing an acceleration measurement would likely yield 
\begin{equation}
a^i = \ddot x^i + \Gamma^i_{jk}\dot x^j \dot x^k
\end{equation}
since this would vanish if the particle is in fact not accelerating and is moving in a straight line.

Is this correct? Would this reasoning also work in more general situations such as the case of a particle constrained to move on a sphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Yes. Clearly an accelerometer can't measure the value of $\ddot x^i$, for the reasons you've given. It measures $F^i$, which is the nongravitational force acting on the particle.